# Natural bijection between equivariant maps and sections, Principal bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

This is in page 11, Prop 6.1 of [Mitchell's notes on Fibre bundles](https://www3.nd.edu/~mbehren1/18.906/prin.pdf). I am quoting the proposition below.

> Let $\pi:P \rightarrow B$ be a principal $G$ bundle, $X$ a right $G$-space. $Hom_G(P,X)$ denotes the set of $G$-equivariant maps, $\Gamma(P \times_G X \rightarrow B)$ denotes the sections of $q$, where $q: P \times_G X \rightarrow B$ is a fibre  bundle map.
>
> Given $ f \in Hom_G(P,X)$, this induces a map $P \rightarrow P \times X$ given by $p \mapsto (p,f(p))$. From UP where $B$ is regarded as $P/G$ of map $\pi$, there is an induced map 
>       $$s=s_f :B \rightarrow P \times_G X$$
>
> There is a natural bijection $\phi:Hom_G(P,X) \rightarrow \Gamma(P \times_G X \rightarrow B)$ given by $f \mapsto s_f$.

The proof is to prove the case when $P=B \times G$ and use this categorial argument.

[image]

I believe this is an argument in category of Sets. But I am completely lost how the first map is the equalizer of the "second two" - how are there two maps?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're asking correctly, the point is that we have $\prod_{i\in I}\text{Hom}_G(P_i,X)$ and $\prod_{i,j\in I}\text{Hom}_G(P_i\cap P_j,X)$. The function between these effectively takes a function on $I$ and produces a function on $I\times I$. So we have an $i$ and $j$, we need to produce an arrow $P_i\cap P_j\to X$, and we have any arrows $P_k\to X$ for our choice of $k$. There are two ways of accomplishing this. Restrict $P_i\to X$ by $P_j$ (i.e. precompose with the injection $P_i\cap P_j\hookrightarrow P_i$) or restrict $P_j\to X$ by $P_i$. These are the two arrows.

Comment: Oh yes, I see, thanks. So for the second map $\prod Hom_G(P_i,X) \rightarrow \prod Hom_G(P_i \cap P_j, X) $ we make a choice of these two?

Comment: As an aside, this "categorical argument" is essentially a sheaf condition and the basis for descent theory.  So it's worth understanding well.